# find max value in associative array with condition

Tags: php

```
$a=2;
$b=6;
$c=7;
$r1=8;
$r2=9;
$r3=6;
$array = array(
  array('MIDDAY'=>$a,'RATE'=>$r1),
  array('SHORTDAY'=>$b,'RATE'=>$r2),
  array('LONGDAY'=>$c,'RATE'=>$r3)
);
```

I have a array like this and i want this array to process
and want to check whose count is greater like as above LONGDAY=7
then i want this LONGDAY key in one variable and its RATE in other variable

And also want to check if two count is equal then like LONGDAY=7 and MIDDAT=7
then i want to check with RATE whose rate is greater then same
i want this LONGDAY key in one variable and its RATE in other variable (for RATE is greater in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should do it to sort the array according to your rules and take the top result.

```
$array = array(
  array('type' => 'MIDDAY',   'val' => $a, 'rate' => $r1),
  array('type' => 'SHORTDAY', 'val' => $b, 'rate' => $r2),
  array('type' => 'LONGDAY',  'val' => $c, 'rate' => $r3)
);

usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if      ($a['val'] < $b['val']) return 1;
    else if ($a['val'] > $b['val']) return -1;
    else    return $b['rate'] - $a['rate'];
});

$var1 = $array[0]['type'];
$var2 = $array[0]['rate'];
```

Note, this uses PHP 5.3+ anonymous function syntax.

Comment: This won't work http://codepad.viper-7.com/sOPMIs And as first problem is easy, second problem is more interesting

Comment: [Fixed](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0m6bvE) so the extraction of the top values works. I'd actually suggest a more uniform array structure, should make things a lot easier.

Comment: What about second problem? I'm pretty sure there can be better solution than mine... Anyways he is looking for highest value in MIDDAY, SHORTDAY, LONGDAY not in RATE

Comment: What second problem? To sort on RATE if the *DAY is equal? That's in there too. Or I don't completely understand the question.

Comment: `And also want to check if two count is equal then like LONGDAY=7 and MIDDAT=7 then i want to check with RATE whose rate is greater then same i want this LONGDAY key in one variable and its RATE in other variable (for RATE is greater in this case)`. And as i said in 1st problem he looks for the highest `MIDDAY, SHORTDAY, LONGDAY`, not the highest `RATE`

Comment: I read this as "sort on *DAY first, if equal, sort on RATE." If the OP means something else, the question needs clarification. :) And yes, this does give him the highest *DAY in `$val` at the end.

Comment: explanation of my question:- 1. condition first find max value in MIDDAY , LONGDAY, and SHORTDAY...if only unique or single max found then store  return related to thier max with MIDDAY, LONGDAY, SHORTDAY key . 2. condition second if two or more similar max found then compare thier return who is max then store return of those max with MIDDAY, LONGDAY and SHORTDAY key.

Comment: @user Sorry, this doesn't really clear it up. Please post some sample input data with the respective output you'd expect.

Comment: K as i have posted my question you can see the array and thier value, now  u can check the value for a,b,c as 2,6,7 right. 1) first case i am checking for MIDDAY, SHORTDAY , and LONGDAY so LONGDAY value  7 , is high . 2) so expected output var1=LONGDAY and var2=$r3.   end of first condition   3) Now check for second condition if i change $b=7 then there is two max value that is SHORTDAY and LONGDAY both are 7 , now i want to compare thier RATE , whose RATE is max if found suppose SHORTDAY ,RATE =9 as u can see $r2 then expected output var1=SHORTDAY, var2=$r2..i think this time it is clear to u

Comment: @vishal Right, which is essentially what my answer did. I updated it to a more sensible array structure so it's easier to extract the *DAY values.

Comment: but this logic is not giving me my result....as i put the value $a=3,$b=4,$c=6 and $r1=7, $r2=6, $r3=9  so for it is returning me LONGDAY and $r3 this is right.......but for second logic as i put $a=3,$b=6,$c=6 and $r1=7, $r2=6, $r3=9 so two value are same as $b and $c that is SHORTDAY and LONGDAY then it shud compare thier $r2 and $r3 so $r3 is 9 which greater than $r2 so result shud be LONGDAY and $r3 k ...

Comment: if i add one more usort as you written ...then only it is giving me perfect answer ...$a=3,$b=6,$c=6 and $r1=7, $r2=6, $r3=9 two value are same as $b and $c that is SHORTDAY and LONGDAY then it shud compare thier $r2 and $r3 so $r3 is 9 which greater than $r2 so result shud be LONGDAY and $r3

Comment: @vishal There you go, fixed a number twister for you. You know, instead of expecting other people to write perfect code for you, why don't you try to *understand* what's going on and adapt it to your own needs?

Comment: `$array = array(
  array('val' => $a, 'rate' => $r1,'type' => 'MIDDAY'),
  array('val' => $b, 'rate' => $r2,'type' => 'SHORTDAY'),
  array('val' => $c, 'rate' => $r3,'type' => 'LONGDAY')
);
foreach($array as $key => $val){
  $max = max($array);
   }` **for me this is working perfect, i tested it and got the output.I think this is small code with perfect output..THANKS**